# How to prevent differences between facebook object debugger and share dialog data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

[image: object debugger]

For some reason the object debugger displays all the data that I want to share with no issues but the share dialog fails to display the image. I have searched the site looking for answers and most of  the solutions recommend clearing the browser cache. I've done this countless times but I still cannot make the share dialog display the image.

According to the open graph specs my image is valid so I do not know what the hell is going on.

How could I approach this? Should I report it as a bug to Facebook?

Is it because my image is not a square?

I have been testing this in a QA environment so it is not because of localhost.

Thanks!